# Zoho CRM API: Python request-based POST or GET authentication + insertion of contacts

Tags: python, django, crm, zoho

#### The Task

A Django application that allows users to sign up and once the user clicks on the account activation link, Zoho CRM is receiving the data and a contact is created in the CRM section.

#### The Problem

I am currently working on an absolute masterpiece - the ZOHO API.
I am struggling to set up the native Python code that uses POST/GET requests.

Regarding the zcrmsdk 3.0.0, I have completely given up on this solution unless somebody can provide a fully functional example. The support simply blames my code.

The documentation I consulted:

- https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/api/v2/access-refresh.html
- https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/api/v2/insert-records.html

Since the post request in postman API works fine I do not understand why it does not work in Python code.

#### My approach

1. Generate an self-client API code on: https://api-console.zoho.com/
2. Insert that code on Postman and retrieve the access or refresh token
3. Use this access token in an add_user_contact function that is defined in the documentation
   It works! Response is success and it is in Zoho CRM

The permsissions scope I am using is: ZohoCRM.modules.contacts.ALL, ZohoCRM.users.ALL, ZohoCRM.modules.deals.ALL, ZohoCRM.modules.attachments.ALL, ZohoCRM.settings.ALL, AAAserver.profile.ALL

#### Pictures of Postman POST request

Header:

[image: the header]

Body:

[image: the body content]

Expected response:

[image: the expected response]

### My own code

```py
def authenticate_crm():

    """
    access to response object id:
    response_object.get('data')[0].get('details').get('id')
    """

    url = 'https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/token'

    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }

    # one time self-client token here -
    request_body = {
        "code": "1000.aa8abec144835ab79b8f9141fa1fb170.8ab194e4e668b8452847c7080c2dd479",
        "redirect_uri": "http://example.com/yourcallback",
        "client_id": "1000.H95VDM1H9KCXIADGF05E0E1XSVZKFQ",
        "client_secret": "290e505ec52685fa62a640d874e6560f2fc8632e97",
       " grant_type": "authorization_code"
    }

    response = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(request_body).encode('utf-8'))
    if response is not None:
        print("HTTP Status Code : " + str(response.status_code))
        print(response.json())
```

I am essentially struggling to convert the Postman API request to a Python request to get the token as part of the workflow. What am I doing wrong here?

The documentation states: Note: For security reasons, pass the below parameters in the body of your request as form-data. (access-refresh link) but passing it in Postman as form-data breaks the call completely.

According to their own documentation (which is convoluted, contradictory and full of outdated screenshots) the authentication key is needed only once.

Once the request from above runs, I would take the response in the third image and use the refresh key to add the contact.

I am also open to a solution with the SDK 3.0.0, if anybody can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it!

I have changed this line:

```
response = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(request_body).encode('utf-8'))
```

to this and added some return statement:

```
payload =     '1000.6d9411488dcac999f02304d1f7843ab2.e14190ee4bae175debf00d2f87143b19&'     \
          'redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fyourcallback&' \
          'client_id=1000.H95VDM1H9KCXIADGF05E0E1XSVZKFQ&' \
         'client_secret=290e505ec52685fa62a640d874e6560f2fc8632e97&'\
          'grant_type=authorization_code'

response = requests.request(method="POST", url=url, headers=headers,     data=payload)
if response is not None:
    print("HTTP Status Code : " + str(response.status_code))
    # print(response.text)
    print(response.json())
    # catch access and refresh token
at = response.json().get('access_token')
rt = response.json().get('refresh_token')

return at, rt
```

I do not understand why that is different but that fixed it and I could retrieve keys from ZOHO.

Comment: for some reason I am getting HTTP Status Code : 200
{'error': 'invalid_client'} , even though the all the stuff is correct : client_id, client_secret. But I do not have a 'redirect_uri'. What should I place for 'redirect_uri' ?

Comment: This gave me an invalid code error response from Zoho. I fixed it by using `payload = 'code=1000.6d9...` instead of `payload = '1000.6d9...`.

Comment: Even though I did get a response, there's no `refresh_token` present.

Comment: [Apparently](https://desk.zoho.com/support/APIDocument.do#RefreshingAccessTokens): "Refresh token can be obtained only when `access_type` is set to `offline` while creating the access token."

Answer (score 0):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67745039/6243352) gave an "invalid code" error. I fixed it by prepending `code=` to the start of the payload. So, instead of:

```py
payload = '1000.6d9411488dcac999f02304d1f7843ab2.e14190ee4bae175debf00d2f87143b19&' \
# ...
```

I used

```py
payload = 'code=1000.6d9411488dcac999f02304d1f7843ab2.e14190ee4bae175debf00d2f87143b19&' \
# ...
```

Since integrating with Zoho was such a pain, I'll include the rest of my script which also shows how to obtain the initial grant token and refresh the access token.

I've tried to clean up the approach in the existing answer to be a bit more maintainable (found below as `get_tokens`), avoiding hand-coded query strings and with better documentation of each step. Hopefully the API won't change too much from the time of posting this to the time you're reading this...

```py
"""
Zoho API access token generator

References:
- https://desk.zoho.com/support/APIDocument.do#OauthTokens
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67643027

"""

import requests
import urllib


# TODO set up your config
client_id = "1000.rn8abwxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
client_secret = "c2b74fxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
redirect_uri = "https://exact-url-from-config.com"
scope = "desk.articles.read"
state = "unused"


def get_auth_url() -> str:
    """Requests a grant token, the first step in the process.
    The response has a location header with a URL that can
    be used to login to Zoho by a user in a browser.

    This should look like:
    # noqa: E501
    curl --dump-header - "https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=1000.rn8wxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&scope=desk.articles.read&redirect_uri=https://exact-url-from-config.com&state=-5466400890088961855&access_type=offline"
    """
    grant_url = "https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/auth"
    params = {
        "response_type": "code",
        "client_id": client_id,
        "scope": scope,
        "redirect_uri": redirect_uri,
        "access_type": "offline",  # required for refresh token
        "state": state,
    }
    response = requests.get(grant_url, params, allow_redirects=False)
    response.raise_for_status()

    if "location" not in response.headers:
        raise ValueError("No location in response headers")

    return response.headers["location"]


def parse_grant_code(redirected_url: str) -> str:
    """Extracts the code= parameter from a URL"""
    query = urllib.parse.urlsplit(redirected_url).query
    grant_code = dict(urllib.parse.parse_qsl(query)).get("code")
    return grant_code


def get_tokens(grant_code: str) -> dict:
    """Given a grant_code (which expires in 1 minute),
    make a request to get the auth tokens.
    Be careful to not make more than 5 refresh tokens in a minute.
    """
    url = "https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/token"
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
    data = {
        "code": grant_code,
        "client_id": client_id,
        "client_secret": client_secret,
        "grant_type": "authorization_code",
        "redirect_uri": redirect_uri,
    }
    response = requests.post(url, data, headers=headers)
    response.raise_for_status()
    return response.json()


def refresh_access(refresh_token: str) -> dict:
    """Uses the refresh token to acquire a new access token"""
    url = "https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/token"
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
    data = {
        "refresh_token": refresh_token,
        "client_id": client_id,
        "client_secret": client_secret,
        "scope": scope,
        "redirect_uri": redirect_uri,
        "grant_type": "refresh_token",
    }
    response = requests.post(url, data, headers=headers)
    response.raise_for_status()
    return response.json()


def get_articles(access_token: str) -> list:
    """Gets a list of articles"""
    url = "https://desk.zoho.com/api/v1/articles"
    headers = {"Authorization": f"Zoho-oauthtoken {access_token}"}
    params = {
        "from": 1,
        "limit": 10,
        "sortBy": "-createdTime",
        "status": "Published",
    }
    response = requests.get(url, params, headers=headers)
    response.raise_for_status()
    return response.json().get("data")


def interactively_get_tokens():
    auth_url = get_auth_url()
    print("Go to the following link in a browser and sign in\n")
    print(auth_url)

    # After logging in, the user will be redirected to a URL
    # that has a code= query parameter known as a grant token.
    # We need this for the next request. It expires in 1 minute.

    # the redirected URL should look like:
    # https://exact-url-from-config.com?state=-5466400890088961855&code=1000.dd3dxxxxxxxxxxx&location=us&accounts-server=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.zoho.com&
    redirected_url = input(
        "\nthen paste the browser's redirected URL here and press Enter: "
    )
    grant_code = parse_grant_code(redirected_url)

    # Now that we have the grant_code, make another request
    # for the tokens. The access_token expires in 1 hour.
    # The refresh_token never expires.
    data = get_tokens(grant_code)
    print("Tokens response JSON:", data)
    access_token = data.get("access_token")
    refresh_token = data.get("refresh_token")
    print("Access token: ", access_token)
    print("Refresh token:", refresh_token)

    # Optionally test the token:
    # print([x["title"] for x in get_articles(access_token)])

    # After an hour, the access token will expire, so
    # create a new one using the refresh token.
    # access_token = refresh_access(refresh_token)
    # print(access_token)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    interactively_get_tokens()
```